# if else preventing loop for passing through object

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, regex

I am having trouble returning a statement when my RegExp finds no matches :

```
function ai(message) { 
    if (username.length < 3) { 
        username = message;
        send_message("Oh, well hello " + username + ", My name is Donald J Trump and i'm a big boy");
    } else {
        for (i = 0; i <= botChat.length; i++) { 
            var re = new RegExp(botChat[i][0], "i"); 
            if (re.test(message)) { 
                var length = botChat[i].length - 1; 
                var index = Math.ceil(length * Math.random()); 
                var reply = botChat[i][index];
                send_message(reply);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I enter a phrase it can correctly match the first line in an array as per the `for` loop. The issue I'm having is when I try to add an `else` statement it ceases to loop through my array properly.

I have tried :

```
else if (re.test(message) === false) {
    send_message("i can't be expected to know everything");
}
```

But it doesn't work, it prevents the loop from looping past `botChat[0][0]`.

I've  also tried :

```
if (send_message().val() == "") {
    // ...
}
```

But every time my code no longer works. Is there a method of adding something to my array that says 'if you don't find a match above, choose this'?

Or just a way of working my code so that the if/else works?

attached is the [codepen](https://codepen.io/BenjieCrumpet/pen/OxNdGa/).

Comment: You haven't shown `botChat` here, but it looks like this code is wasting a lot of time compiling and recompiling regular expressions when you should probably do that once per initialization.

Comment: `for (i = 0; i <= botChat.length; i++)` if botChat.length gives you the length of the first dimension, there is nothing within the for block that stops the increment `i++`. botChat is not reassigned, nor is the loop var `i` changed. What kind of problem you got ? The only place you can add else is  if (re.test(message)) {}`else{}` The re is in scope with the for block, so it has to be some other problem. You could try to comment out the if block and print the loop var `i` on each pass.

Comment: If I've understood correctly then the simplest solution would be to `return` straight after you call `send_message` so that it doesn't continue to process the loop. You could then put your 'else' handling after the end of the loop. I don't follow why you're calling `.val()`, it seems like you're randomly invoking a jQuery method for accessing an input value even though `send_message` doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 0):

I checked your codepen and the lines 190 and 194 `console.log(send_message().val());` seems to be breaking the loop because those lines are throwing an exception since `send_message()` returns `undefined` and `undefined` does not have the `.val()` method.

Your regular expressions are working fine. I recommend not creating new RegExp objects every iteration, instead, use the one defined in the array `if (botChat[i][0].test(message))`, the overhead will be less.

Comment: thanks for looking into it. The loop breaks even without the console.log(). I've replaced the new variable and changed it to be just a simple if/else but it no longer passes through any of the other objects in the array, botchat, except for the first object

Comment: (i = 0; i <= botChat.length; i++) { 
        if (botChat[i][0].test(message)) { 
          var length = botChat[i].length - 1; 
          var index = Math.ceil(length * Math.random());
          var reply = botChat[i][index]; 
          send_message(reply);
          return;
        }
        else {
          send_message("i don't understand");
          return;